# Generate and serve a file with flask

Tags: python, flask

So I have a script run_queries() that run some SQL queries and writes them to a xml file under the merge_files directory.

I want to create a simple flask app for running that run_quries() task, then after it finishes download the the most recent XML file.

This code I have works fine for the first time I run it, however it seems like flask or my browser is doing some caching. Because after the first time it doesnt even run this code, it just instantly returns and always gives back the same file.

How can i fix this

```
@app.route('/get_analytics')
def get_analytics():
    run_query()
    list_of_files = glob.glob('./merge_files/*')
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    response = send_file(latest_file, as_attachment=True,
                         attachment_filename=latest_file)
    response.headers["x-filename"] = latest_file
    response.headers["Access-Control-Expose-Headers"] = 'x-filename'
    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask [`send_file`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.send_file) accepts `cache_timeout` parameter which you can set to `-1` to disable the cache. Alternatively, you can specify cache timeout in the configuration using `SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT` setting.

Comment: Thanks i ended up doing the second approach